# Zend 3 onBootstrap get adapter

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I started using zend 3 a few months ago for a project and now I'm stuck.
I have a customized authentication (not using zend authentication module) which is working fine but I need to validate every time i access a redirected page.

Because on every page's url goes a token that is used to check in database, and I'm trying to do inside the function `onBootStrap()`.

I learned to use factories, models, mappers and I'm currently using them in some controllers, but i can't find a way to achieve, at least if i could get the `dbAdapter` from the bootstrap event to use, it will be enough.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use lazy event for this job. here's you are a simple example.

```
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e)
{
   /** @var \Interop\Container\ContainerInterface $container */
   $container = $e->getApplication()->getserviceManager();

   $events = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

   $events->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, new LazyListener([
      'listener' => Listener::class,
      'method'   => 'onRoute'
   ], $container));
}
```

So you can check you auth on Listener class' "onRoute" method. If MvcEvent::ROUTE event is too early for you, you can use other MvcEvents too.

Hope this can solve your problem.

Comment: Also you can use middleware too if you will have to check for a specific route group.

Comment: Thanks, i was searching for something more simple. I answered with my solution.

Comment: Ya that's do work too. But Also it creates table instance  on application bootstrap. Route may not require to check token or even may not found route (404). Doesn't matter for this code block. It will create instance which is mean wasted ram.

Answer (score 0):

To get the adapter and use it in tablegateway

```
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $event){
       $container = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
       $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);

       $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
       $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new TableObjectClass());

       $tableGateway = new TableGateway("Table name", $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
       $mapper = new TableObjectClassMapper($tableGateway);

       //and use $mapper to get data from the table and store it as TableObjectClass
       $data = $mapper->fetch()->current();
    }
```